# Trying to match number with a symbol

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a block of text that reads something like the following:

> Claw. Melee Weapon Attack: +11 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit:
>   14 (2d6 + 7) slashing damage plus 7 (2d6) cold damage.

I am trying to match the `+11` which may also be `-3` or something like that. My current regex pattern is `[+-−]\d+` which does get the `+11` but it does also match the 5 and the 7.

I have been using regexr.com to help me, but my novice level of using regex is making it rather complicated for me to figure out.

So my question is, using regex is there a way to match the +11 but not the `5` or `7`?

Okay, so I got this to work `(\+|\-|\−)\d+` but am going to leave this open to see if anyone offers a better solution.

Comment: so you want to match any number that has a `+` or a `-` in front of it?

Comment: `[+-−]\d+` Matches any character in the range from `+` to `−`, which is **a lot** of characters (around 8700 characters). Change your regex to `[+−-]\d+`

Comment: Why do you have two dashes in your regex? `[+-]\d+` works for me

Comment: @AndrewLohr basically

Comment: @ctwheels yeah I just figured that out, I updated the code to include a working-ish version. Not sure if it is the best way.

Comment: Your update only works if that is the only number to ever have an immediate, preceding +/-. If the `+ 7` was to ever be `+7` or something like that, you may find issues. Could you target 'Attack: ' plus the value then parse out the number.

Comment: @GalAbra because sometimes the website uses a minus symbol and other times they use the em dash (which basically look the same, but are different characters) So I have to match on both

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh you don't need to escape every character, just `-`, but you can simply put it at the start or end of the set such that it doesn't create a range: `[+−-]\d+`. Also, you don't need to put `|` in sets.

Comment: @ctwheels something like this `(\+|-|−)\d+`

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh `[+−-]\d+`

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh If you want to include em-dash, use this: `[+\-\u2014]\d+`

Comment: @ctwheels what how is that different from mine, did you flip that minus and dash?

Comment: @RobertE.McIntosh precisely.

Comment: @ctwheels, you've misspelled your regex. You mean `[+-]`?

Comment: You can use: `(Attack: )([+,-])\d`. Then parse out the number from the response.

Comment: @KoshVery no, I'm using the same symbols as OP. `−-` are different symbols

Comment: @ctwheels if you would post yours as an answer, I can mark it as correct. Since it appears to be the working version I am going to use.

Comment: @ctwheels, haha, thanks! minus to the first or to the last place then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex contains `[+-−]`. This is trying to match a character range from `+` (index 43) to `−` (index 8722): That's a lot of characters! You need to stop the `-` from creating a range.

**Note**: `-` and `−` are two different characters.

The three patterns below are all equivalent. Placing the hyphen at the start or end of a set or escaping it matches the `-` character literally.

```
[+−-]\d+
[+\-−]\d+
[-+−]\d+
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where you use it:

- if you decide to split it using `someString.split(...)` you can simply add a limit, from the String start til the first matched block.
- Otherwise try this regex: `^(?>.)+[+−-]\d+`

  - `?<` = match if preceded by what comes after it
  - `^` = matches string start
  - `[.]+` = any amount of characters
  - `[+-]\d+` = the format you specified
- Also if you want to make it more specic try: `(?>Attack:\s)[+−-]\d+`

I am not sure if regex tools are up to date enough to incorporate the lookahead and behind functionality (I used IntelliJ's built in regexp checker)

*Edit* As some already pointed out [+-−] would treat the characters from + to -, therefore use `[+−-]` or `[+\-−]` instead, to escape the - being treated as special regexp character.